# resample before pct_change() and missing values

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'G1', '2019-01-01', 11],
             ['A', 'G1', '2019-01-02', 12], 
             ['A', 'G1', '2019-01-04', 14], 
             ['B', 'G2', '2019-01-01', 11], 
             ['B', 'G2', '2019-01-03', 13], 
             ['B', 'G2', '2019-01-06', 16]], 
            columns=['cust', 'group', 'date', 'val'])
df
```

[image]

```
df = df.groupby(['cust', 'group', 'date']).sum()
df
```

[image]

The dataframe is grouped and now I would like to calculate `pct_change`, but only if there are previous date.
If I do it like this:

```
df['pct'] = df.groupby(['cust', 'group']).val.pct_change()
df
```

[image]

I will get `pct_change`, but with no respect to the missing dates.
For example in group `('A', 'G1')`, `pct` for date `2019-01-04` should be `np.nan` because there is no (previous) date `2019-01-03`.

Maybe the solution would be to resample by day, where each new row will have `np.nan` as `val`, and than to do `pct_change`.

I tried to use `df.resample('1D', level=2)` but than I get an error:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'

For group `('B', 'G2')` all `pct_change` should be `np.nan` because none of the rows has previous date.

Expected result is:

[image]

How to calculate `pct_change` respecting missing dates?

Solution:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for x, y  in df.groupby(['cust', 'group']):
    resampled=y.set_index('date').resample('D').val.mean().to_frame().rename({'val': 'resamp_val'}, axis=1) 
    resampled = resampled.join(y.set_index('date')).fillna({'cust':x[0],'group':x[1]})
    resampled['resamp_val_pct'] = resampled.resamp_val.pct_change(fill_method=None)

    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, resampled])

new_df = new_df[['cust', 'group', 'val', 'resamp_val', 'resamp_val_pct']]
new_df
```

[image]

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I just provided expected result.

Answer (score 3):

Check with `groupby`, then you need `resample` first and get the pct change with Boolean mask, since pct_change will ignore `NaN`.

```
d={}
for x, y  in df.groupby(['cust', 'group']):
    s = y.set_index('date').resample('D').val.mean()
    d[x] = pd.concat([s, s.pct_change().mask(s.shift().isnull()|s.isnull())], 1)
newdf = pd.concat(d)
newdf.columns = ['val', 'pct']
newdf
Out[651]: 
                  val       pct
     date                      
A G1 2019-01-01  11.0       NaN
     2019-01-02  12.0  0.090909
     2019-01-03   NaN       NaN
     2019-01-04  14.0       NaN
B G2 2019-01-01  11.0       NaN
     2019-01-02   NaN       NaN
     2019-01-03  13.0       NaN
     2019-01-04   NaN       NaN
     2019-01-05   NaN       NaN
     2019-01-06  16.0       NaN
```

You can add `reset_index(inplace=True)` at the end to make all index back to columns

Comment: First I read the answer from AI_Learning in which I asked for resampling by group, the solution you have provided. 

I modified your example a bit, I will edit my question in order to present the solution.

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try comparing the difference between the consecutive rows is not equal to 1 day and then change the pct_change.

```
df= df.groupby(['cust', 'group', 'date'])\
      .agg({'val':'sum','date':[min,max]}).reset_index()
df.columns = ['%s%s' % (a, '_%s' % b if b else '') for a, b in df.columns]

df['date_diff']=df['date'].diff()
df['pct_change_val']=df.val_sum.pct_change()
df['pct_change_final'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.NaN if pd.isnull(row.date_diff) \
                                  else np.NaN if row.date_diff != np.timedelta64(1, 'D') else row.pct_change_val ,axis=1)


#output:

    cust    group   date    date_min    date_max    val_sum date_diff   pct_change_val  pct_change_final
0   A   G1  2019-01-01  2019-01-01  2019-01-01  11          
1   A   G1  2019-01-02  2019-01-02  2019-01-02  12  1 days 00:00:00.000000000   0.09090909090909083 0.09090909090909083
2   A   G1  2019-01-04  2019-01-04  2019-01-04  14  2 days 00:00:00.000000000   0.16666666666666674 
3   B   G2  2019-01-01  2019-01-01  2019-01-01  11  -3 days +00:00:00.000000000 -0.2142857142857143 
4   B   G2  2019-01-03  2019-01-03  2019-01-03  13  2 days 00:00:00.000000000   0.18181818181818188 
5   B   G2  2019-01-06  2019-01-06  2019-01-06  16  3 days 00:00:00.000000000   0.23076923076923084
```

Comment: This works. Thanks.

I got an idea for another approach.
Would it be possible to find min/max dates for each group and than resample by day?
Afterwards, I could use pct_change.

For example if for group X min date is 2019-01-01 and max is 2019-01-05, I could resample the group, and than do the same for rest of groups.
In that way I will have a dataframe in proper format for pct_change (and some others operations).